# Css broken when uploaded to server- works 100% on localhost

Tags: html, css

My site looks great when it's hosted on my own pc, using WAMP. But when I upload to my host, few of the classes correctly feed from my css doc, even though the doc is the same one. In both instances I test on chrome.

You can see it for yourself. Here is my homepage http://www.leagueuniversity.com/ it looks like a pile of nonsense, because the css doc http://www.leagueuniversity.com/css/styles.css is not being referenced from properly- yet it works fine when the same files are hosted locally.

One thing I did notice, is that the css doc linked above has no word wrap when uploaded, yet has proper formatting/word wrap etc when hosted locally, even though it's the same doc and viewed on the same browser. What!?

Comment: Yes, the CSS is actually broken. What tool and protocol are you using to upload the file to the server?

Answer (score 3):

The file is being loaded fine. There is, however an error in the code. In the first line is says "margin: auto;'}". The single colon breaks it, because everything that follows gets interpreted as string.

I don't know WAMP, but there might be something involved that fixes the error where it doesn't on the remote server.

Comment: Also, consider a more decent browser. I don't know what you're developing in, but small mistakes as these should be obvious in every developer/inspector mode.

Comment: thanks so much buddy. I feel like a bit of an idiot now- I just assumed that there were no mistakes if it works locally. Thanks!

Comment: How did you transfer your site on the real server? by copying and pasting the code or by uploading your files?

Answer (score 2):

**You CSS contains errors**

[Validating your CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) displays some errors:

```css
padding:20px, 20px, 20px, 20px;
…
float:left clear:both;
…
clip-path:polygon(0px208px,146.5px207px,147px141.2px,...);
```

Fix them like that:

```css
padding:20px;
…
float:left;
clear:both;
…
clip-path:polygon(0px 208px, 146.5px 207px, 147px 141.2px);
```

Comment: Thanks man! That is a useful site that I wasn't aware of. Thanks!